# PAM vs /etc/shadow in Dovecot SASL configuration - Security differences?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, pam, sasl, shadow

I set up a server with Postfix SMTP auth through Dovecot SASL. However, it was not possible to get the  PAM authentification working as standard out of the box.

So more by chance, I changed it to the *shadow* driver as explained in [Dovecot documentation](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/Shadow) and the configuration and setup runs fine immediately.

Are there any drawbacks keeping the `/etc/shadow` as password database in Dovecot's config? Especially, does it impact Postfix/Dovecot/Servers's security anyhow? The documentation just says, "PAM is usually preferred" but does not explain further why.

Answer (score 0):

PAM stands for Pluggable Authentication Modules. It provides a more configurable method of trusted system authentication, by using modules to extend functionality. This allows for users to be authenticated through sources other than `/etc/shadow`(e.x. Kerberos) and enables programs to authenticate users without being given root or read access to `/etc/shadow`. If you don't have PAM configured to use a source other than `/etc/shadow`, it is functionally the same as far as Dovecot is concerned.

Answer (score -1):

Could not make Dovecot working with PAM password database (passdb), Virtualmin/Usermin users keep getting error "Usermin Failed to login to IMAP server : [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed."

Changing passdb driver to /etc/shadow however fixed the problem immediately.

Probably issue with Virtualmin/Dovecot is in permissions to mailbox/inbox.imap or other config files.